# Remove the bootscreen in Fedora 15

Tags: netbook, eee-pc, fedora-15

I use Fedora 15 on my Asus eeePC 1015P and I wonder if there is a way to remove the normal boot animation (the fedora logo thing / the loading bars) and see the console output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either remove `rhgb` from the `kernel` line in the grub configuration in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`, or use `plymouth-set-default-theme` to select one of the text-only themes.

---

The following details are valid for Fedora 18.

### grub

Kernel command line is configured in `/etc/grub2/grub.conf`. This file is generated based on various configuration files under `/etc/` directory.

The default kernel command line is provided in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable set in `/etc/default/grub`. Remove `rhgb` (or synonym `splash`) option and update grub configuration by running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` command.

### plymouth

Use `plymouth-set-default-theme details` command to set theme which disables graphics and shows logs. Current theme is shown by running `plymouth-set-default-theme` without any option. The available themes are listed by `--list` option.

The effective settings used during the boot are actually in `initramfs` image which has to be updated after changing theme settings. Invoke `/usr/libexec/plymouth/plymouth-update-initrd` command (note the full path) to make changes effective.

Comment: I will check this asap.